# parse gawk over list of files in directory and save to new folder

Tags: text-processing, awk

Hello I have the following code

```
for i in *.dssp ; do
   gawk 'BEGIN{ FIELDWIDTHS = "5 5 1 1 4 1 *"} $4 == "A" {s=s$6} END {print s}' | tr "[HGI]" "H" | tr "[BE]" "E" | tr "[TS ' ']" "C" 
done
```

I am able to execute successfully by calling the code in the shell with one specific .dssp file, however I have a directory of these files and need it to loop over the entire lot of them and save the output which is a bunch of letter (fasta like) into a new file with the corresponding id that it pulled from. I am not sure where to go from here

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Not sure you understand what `tr` does as `tr "[TS ' ']" ...` or anything else that lists the same chars multiple times in the bracket expression doesn't make sense. Please read the `tr` man page and [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you.

Comment: But that part works perfectly fine!

Comment: Does it? I'm sure when you wrote `tr "[TS ' ']" "C"` whatever you were hoping that would do isn't what it actually does or you'd never have written it that way so maybe you just haven't noticed it messing up your data or maybe you haven't hit that case in your testing yet? It's also not clear why you'd write `tr "[HGI]" "H"` or `tr "[BE]" "E"` but those aren't as likely to be just plain wrong. If you [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output then we can help you.

Answer (score 3):

Use awk alone here:

```
gawk -v map='[GI]>H,B>E,[TS ]>C' '
BEGIN  { nrf=split(map, tmp, /[,>]/); FIELDWIDTHS="5 5 1 1 4 1 *" }

$4=="A"{ buf= buf $6 }

ENDFILE{
    for(i=1; i<=nrf; i+=2) gsub(tmp[i], tmp[i+1], buf);
    print buf >FILENAME".output"; close(FILENAME".output"); buf=""
}' ./*.dssp
```

Here in `-v map='[GI]>H,B>E,[TS ]>C'` we are passing the characters mapping conversion to awk (each separated with a comma; the `>` is also used for more readability between each mapping group) as a variable parameter.

then inside the BEGIN{} block we split the mapping came from the *`map`* variable into temporary array *`tmp`* and considered both those `,` and `>` as the separators; we also defined the fields by the FIELDWIDTHS (GNU awk).

next we do checking if the 4<sup>th</sup> field is equal to "A" character, if so, then buffer the 6<sup>th</sup> field in appending mode from each line into *`buff`* variable.

at the end of every input file we process the ENDFILE{} block (GNU awk), and here we do loop over the mapping pairs of characters and replace left-hand characters with their right-hand ones in the *`buff`* variable; and after that we print the updated *`buff`* content to a output file with the same name as the input with a added suffix like "fileName.output".

Comment: Thank you. I will try this, this all seems greek to me, but hopefully I can make it run.

Comment: @bioinformatic89 you are welcome! see also [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)